# How is Windows able to connect to a Wi-Fi network and also share internet over Wi-Fi while other OSes can't?

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, internet-sharing

In Windows, we are able to simultaneously connect to a network over Wi-Fi and also share that network to other devices over Wi-Fi using third-party tools like Connectify or whatever. But, why is that on other OSes like OS X, Linux, iOS, Android we can't do this? What is going on in Windows? And can this be done in other OSes with a workaround or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is begin with windows 7 new technology called "Virtual Wi-Fi" that is built into Windows 7 and Windows 8, your Windows laptop can create a Wi-Fi hotspot, even while it stays connected to another Wi-Fi network!!!

you can find more info about "Virtual Wi-Fi" from below link:

[MS Tech net old info about virtual WiFi](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/virtualwifi/)

why using Connectify use below shareware called "Virtual Wi-Fi Router"

[More Info And Download](http://www.virtualwifirouter.com/)